# Segmentation fault: 11 / RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Tags: python, recursion, segmentation-fault, binary-search

for my project, I am coding a binary search function (this is my first project!) However, when I try to implement a list that is >= 10, I get the recursion error. By looking at some answers in this site, I've roughly learned and am assuming python sets a recursion limit so that it will prevent stack overflow. So I implemented someone's solution:

```
import sys  
sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)
```

which lead to the following error:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Here is my code:

```
import random
import time
import sys  
sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)

# Implementation of binary search algorithm

# Proving that binary search is faster than naive search

# naive search: scan entire list and ask if it's equal to the target
# if yes, return index
# of no, then return -1 
def naive_search(l,target):
    # example l = [1,3,5,10,12]
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if l[i] == target:
            return i
    return -1
        

# binary search: devide and conquer 
# Leveraging the fact that our list is sorted 
def binary_search(l,target,low = None, high = None):
    if low is None:
        low = 0
    if high is None:
        high = len(l) - 1 
    if high < low:
        return -1

    # example l = [1,3,5,10,12] # should return 3 
    midpoint = (low + high) // 2  # 2
    
    if l[midpoint] == target:
        return midpoint
    elif target < l[midpoint]:
        return binary_search(l, target,low = None, high = midpoint - 1) 
    else:
        # target > l[midpoint]
        return binary_search(l, target, low = midpoint + 1, high = None)

    
if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    
    l = [1, 3, 5, 10, 12, 15, 35, 40, 45]
    target = 10
    print(naive_search(l,target))
    print(binary_search(l,target))
    
"""
    length = 10
    # build a sorted list of length 1000
    sorted_list = set()
    while len(sorted_list) < length:
        sorted_list.add(random.randint(-3*length, 3*length)) 
    sorted_list = sorted(list(sorted_list))   
    print(sorted_list)
""" 
"""
    l = sorted_list
    target = 10
    print(binary_search(l,target))
"""
```

The youtube tutorial that I looked didn't have this problem so I'm really confused.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ext9G7xspg&t=9094s
@ 1:26:00
Thank you for your time.

Comment: `sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)` is almost *never what you should do*. there's a good reason for that recursion limit, and if your implementation needs more, it should just not be recursive

Comment: Almost certainly, the issue here is that you have a bug that is causing infinite recursion

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out I realized - with the help of Tim - it was an infinite recursion (or close to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Method 1

The issue lies in the recursive calls:

```
    elif target < l[midpoint]:
        return binary_search(l, target,low = None, high = midpoint - 1) 
    else:
        # target > l[midpoint]
        return binary_search(l, target, low = midpoint + 1, high = None)
```

You want to copy the `low`, and `high` rather than setting them to `None`. The correct call should be:

```
    elif target < l[midpoint]:
        return binary_search(l, target,low = low, high = midpoint - 1) 
    else:
        # target > l[midpoint]
        return binary_search(l, target, low = midpoint + 1, high = high)
```

---

To demonstrate the bug:

Using your example, in the original call: `low=0, high=8`

Then, in the 1st recursion, `low=0, high=4`.

Now, `target=10 > midpoint=5`, you code makes the following call

```
binary_search(l, target, low = midpoint + 1, high = None)
```

Since `high=None`, it will be set to `high=8` in the next recursion, giving you `low=3, high=8`. This is **not** what you want, since you already eliminated the top half. So you need to carry over `low` and `high` in the recursive call rather than setting them to `None`.

To be more efficient, you can also check `l[low]` and `l[high]` in addition to `l[midpoint]` against the target.

---

### Method 2

Alternatively, you can give a subset of the list in the recursive call. Then, you don't really need the `low` and `high` argument any more. Since slicing only generate new references rather than copies, it doesn't have too much impact on memory.

```
    elif target < l[midpoint]:
        return binary_search(l[low:midpoint], target,low = None, high = None) 
    else:
        # target > l[midpoint]
        return binary_search(l[midpoint+1:high+1], target, low = None, high = None)
```

Comment: Ohhhh that makes so much more sense. I was resetting the parameters of my low and high every recursion so it basically iterated all half of the list! Thanks a lot Tim!